# CosmosDB for Mongo throwing "Detected stuck collection metadata"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Node application running on Azure using CosmosDB for Mongo. Watching the logs, I saw an increase of MongoServerError with the following message:

```
[ActivityId=<UUID>] Detected stuck collection metadata for <collectionName>
```

Where `<UUID>` is a UUIDv4 and `<collectionName>`  is the collection we are currently using.

I'm sorry for the lack of information, but I really have no idea what's happening. I've been unable to find any resource online regarding this error. Not only that, but I'm  not really sure if it's a "real error" since I have not found anything mentioning it.

The only thing similar to this is this [article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87539/mongo-db-sharded-the-collections-metadata-lock-is-taken-issue-coming-very-fre).

If it helps, we are using these packages:

- `mongoose`: 6.10.3
- `@nestjs/mongoose`: 9.2.1
- `@nestjs/common`: 9.0.0

Comment: I have seen that error before when running a `createIndex` - I was advised by support that running `reIndex` would solve it. It didn't in my case but maybe you will have more luck! For me I was just seeing it in a non prod collection and recreated it

Comment: After some testing, it looks like it's related with the index creation, as said by @MartinSmith. When using CosmosDB for Mongo, looks like keeping forward and backward compatibility between schema's indexes is very important.